# Aggregate character string into vector in R

Tags: r, arrays, vector, data.table, string-aggregation

I have a data table `test`:

| id | key |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2365 |
| 1 | 2365 |
| 1 | 3709 |
| 2 | 6734 |
| 2 | 1908 |
| 2 | 4523 |

I want to aggregate unique `key` values by `id` into vector using `data.table` package.

Expected output:

| id | key_array |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "2365", "3709" |
| 2 | "6734", "1908", "4523" |

So, this should work like `array_agg` sql function.

I tried:
`res <- test[, list(key_array = paste(unique(key), collapse = ", ")), by = "id"]`, but I get just a string. But I need to have opportunity to find the length of each vector and operate with its certain elements (find the intersection of two vectors for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1. Base R

This an `aggregate` one-liner.

```r
x <- 'id    key
1   2365
1   2365
1   3709
2   6734
2   1908
2   4523'
test <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)

aggregate(key ~ id, test, \(x) c(unique(x)))
#>   id              key
#> 1  1       2365, 3709
#> 2  2 6734, 1908, 4523
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

But if user @Chris's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72623456/aggregate-character-string-into-vector-in-r/72623626?noredirect=1#comment128285522_72623626) is right then the right solution  as follows.

```
aggregate(key ~ id, test, \(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ", "))
```

Note that both `c(unique(x))` and `as.character(c(unique(x)))` will output a list column, so the latter solution is right anyway.

---

## 2. Package `data.table`

Once again a one-liner.

The output is a list column, with each list member an integer vector. To keep as integers use

```
list(unique(key))
```

instead.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(data.table))

res <- setDT(test)[, .(key_array = list(as.character(unique(key)))), by = id]
res
#>    id      key_array
#> 1:  1      2365,3709
#> 2:  2 6734,1908,4523

str(res)
#> Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ id       : int  1 2
#>  $ key_array:List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr  "2365" "3709"
#>   ..$ : chr  "6734" "1908" "4523"
#>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Then, in order to access the vectors use two extractors, one to extract the column and the other one to extract the vectors.

```r
res$key_array[[1]]
#> [1] "2365" "3709"
res$key_array[[2]]
#> [1] "6734" "1908" "4523"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## 3. `dplyr` solution

Group by `id` and collapse the unique strings into one only.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

test %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(key_array = paste(unique(key), collapse = ", "))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>      id key_array  
#>   <int> <chr>           
#> 1     1 2365, 3709      
#> 2     2 6734, 1908, 4523
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: For whatever reason, it appears `as.character(c(unique(x))))` is desired output. Just speaking to `base::aggregate` here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Rui! I'm interested in a `data.table` approach and your solution ```setDT(test)[, .(key_array = paste(unique(key), collapse = ", ")), by = id]``` is the same as mine, but unfortunately it gives a string instead of a vector

Comment: @Hilary Changed, see if this is what you want. Also, should I remove the `dplyr` solution, since it is not asked for?

Comment: It is not necessary to remove the `dplyr` solution, maybe it will be useful to someone else

Comment: @Hilary Got it, will keep all solutions.